# NSVisualEffectView stops working of NSWindow title bar is set to hide

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

NSVisualEffectView seems to work just fine in a NSWindow, however it stops working (i.e. does not blur contents behind window) if I set the NSWindow's title bar to be hidden from Interface Builder. I don't see why the two are linked but would like to have a borderless window with the blur working - is this not possible?

Comment: Can you describe how your visual effect view is configured? For example: what's your `blendingMode`? Are you subclassing `NSVisualEffectView`?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's set to blur 'Behind Window'. Material: Dark. State: Match Window State. No I'm not subclassing anything. I just created a new project with nothing but a NSWindow and added NSVisualEffectView to my View Controller. Unchecked the 'title bar' and it stops blurring.

Comment: Okay I got it to work by using a hack. First keep the titlebar showing. Next, in my windowDidLoad method for the Window Controller, I simply set 'titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES' along with a 'Full screen contentview' setting in xcode. This keeps the blur.

Comment: If you turned on layer backing for the visual effect view, this might explain the odd behavior. You're specifically not supposed to turn on layer backing for visual effects views. Not sure if that helps.